# Stream of Kth smallest number using maxheap and minheap

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap

I was coding Python program that calculates the sum of `m[i]`, which is the (i//3+1)<sup>th</sup> smallest value among `A[0], A[1], ..., A[i]` values, using a maxHeap and a minHeap.

Here is the code I have written.

```py
import heapq

def find_m(A):
    n = len(A)
    min_heap = []
    max_heap = []
    m = []
    for i in range(n):
        if len(max_heap) < i // 3 + 1:
            heapq.heappush(max_heap, -A[i])
        else:
            if A[i] < -max_heap[0]:
                heapq.heappush(min_heap, -heapq.heappop(max_heap))
                heapq.heappush(max_heap, -A[i])
            else:
                heapq.heappush(min_heap, A[i])
        m.append(-max_heap[0])
    return sum(m)


_list = [11, 12, -20, 14, -10, -8, -7, -6, -4, -2]
print(find_m(_list))
```

Expected output:

```
-38
```

Output I got instead:

```
-27
```

The values that **should** have been summed up (`m`) are:

```
11, 11, -20, 11, -10, -10, -8, -8, -8, -7
```

But I found that my code adds these values:

```
11, 11, -20, 14, -10, -10, -7, -7, -7, -2
```

My intention was to store the lesser values in a max heap, which should have size `i//3+1`, and the greater values in a min heap. That way the root of the max heap should always have the desired value.

It is clear that things go wrong at the moment the value 14 is processed. That value is added to the result, while 11 should have been added instead.

What is the mistake I made?

Comment: You have a small failing example. what an opportunity to learn about debugging. (Works even with pen and paper and some prints-outputs in your code).

Answer (score 2):

At every moment you must ensure that the roots of both heaps are in the right relation, i.e. the following invariant must be ensured when both heaps are non-empty:

```py
-max_heap[0] <= min_heap[0]
```

Your code does not always do that. For instance in the first `if` block a value gets added to the max heap, but as a result the above invariant might be violated. This is the case when the value 14 gets added in your example, because at that moment the max heap has too few elements (so it needs one more), but the min heap's root has value 12, so it really should be that value 12 that gets moved to the max heap. A similar problem can occur (in the opposite sense) with the final `else` block.

Here is a correction:

```py
def find_m(A):
    min_heap = []
    max_heap = []
    m = []
    for i, value in enumerate(A):  # Use enumerate to get both the index and the value
        if len(max_heap) < i // 3 + 1:
            # If current value would cause a violation of the invariant, exchange it 
            #    with the minimum value in the min heap
            if min_heap and value > min_heap[0]:   
                value = heapq.heappushpop(min_heap, value)
            heapq.heappush(max_heap, -value)
        else:
            # If current value would cause a violation of the invariant, exchange it 
            #    with the maximum value in the max heap
            if value < -max_heap[0]:
                value = -heapq.heappushpop(max_heap, -value)
            heapq.heappush(min_heap, value)
        m.append(-max_heap[0])
    return sum(m)
```

Comment: I guess it's good for clarity to check `if min_heap and value > min_heap[0]` yourself, but note that `heappushpop` [also checks that](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/abd6e97020e5773ce2136228e31930a6d9e82dc0/Lib/heapq.py#L163-L168) anyway. My benchmark shows it makes only a small difference to check it yourself (the times for `trincot2` and `trincot3`).

Comment: Yes, @Kelly, that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to ensure the invariant mentioned by trincot. My `heappushpop(max_heap, -a)` makes sure that `max_heap` still has the smallest numbers, so after pushing into `min_heap`, the new number is incorporated into the heaps and the invariant holds. Then just transfer one number from `min_heap` to `max_heap` whenever needed.

```py
from heapq import heappush, heappop, heappushpop

def find_m(A):
    min_heap = []
    max_heap = []
    total = 0
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        heappush(min_heap, -heappushpop(max_heap, -a))
        if not i % 3:
            heappush(max_heap, -heappop(min_heap))
        total -= max_heap[0]
    return total


# Your test
_list = [11, 12, -20, 14, -10, -8, -7, -6, -4, -2]
print(find_m(_list))

# Inefficient but obviously correct reference solution
def naive(A):
    return sum(
        sorted(A[:i+1])[i//3]
        for i in range(len(A))
    )

# Random tests
import random
for n in range(100):
    for _ in range(10):
        A = random.choices(range(1000), k=n)
        expect = naive(A)
        result = find_m(A)
        assert result == expect
print ('done')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVPNbtswDD7sND0FgWGojTmrnQ5dUcCHHHfdbQiCQLWpRahNefop2mfZpZftofY0oyxHziZAgEiKH7-PlH7-nl78ydDr66_g1ebuz5u3ypoRTiinH6DHyVg_G1NwpyqdzFRlFxtC9KhAaeqPY7Er7wXwGjUd4x1oYX9IHvn8n8cbLwc269lSxoKuQIImQAojWukx48V1rlmcwSvYXPAozhXYLcsyp2kFZDxoeA83K9i_gGvmojDXuABKfDdtlrKvkxCLPlhKcSHEO_hmggWPzovjoJ2PkpumgmbLBbY1Hz7xoeHD5o73Z963vKNzexCT1eSLpZ9zPnNg0C-ESulOI3l4CB7Mw5M2wQ0v0BlrsfPMQ6FF6hCcGYLXhubRkNRPaycXsi6MRVbmeMrYF7v9vf7QHMq9vr6-OeToPJk4FivpOxYDEoOltszEvkrq-clEvU4sT8bOPhFTaU1t6nphEQPHy8DFnHfcr5T_sTsZ3aErcnpdVvDY0joUfJ6i9DarzBGLLgwxkp9mDknnMJJcbrQLSmo9FFe9Ibwq049YPsb5g_wF)

Benchmarks, out of curiosity, with 100,000 random numbers:

```
 66.58 ± 0.75 ms  trincot4
 69.71 ± 0.43 ms  trincot2
 70.01 ± 0.81 ms  trincot3
 78.47 ± 1.13 ms  Kelly2
 84.78 ± 0.90 ms  Kelly
 98.80 ± 1.66 ms  trincot
```

Code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=xVfNTttAEL5b6juMhCps6iRAoGojUolj1aq3niKULPaarGrvBu86hCKepBcu5d5X6GP0aTr747-Q0EBp8SXe2fn95tvN-Nvt7FJNBb-5-V6opPPm14vbLcguQeTsjHGSejFN4ANN00v_OBiAB_hkjI-nlMxgCKMTKyGLJYkSiqS43DWrROTAQiDAOFBeZDQnimqHZlc_2npWyKlfOg-hU8pmYuaXEVBMgqAyYwlwoYDBS-jXztoOa0sj085cjIYjm29nWJUy2rWF5FQVObf7nrcFYqZYxr7SGC6YmkIqIrSbk5yR05RK0CF7GKPnEq_x26_q1Vsh4GYITguBKvMNwWUZQqP-f4b7MuaPxnsZ67_DGYFWOeORUNuyzUUnrorYBJSsfnWIzEla0DuoAGzBZ0lrIaYDZ1TBqcBWq6m2iOkCCI_NynhpYpNSXmEQwBHi1OtBH17BXhusLXifQFTkOeXK5XIhijSGiBQYn8CciZQoJjiIxAU2HOMqBLqIpoSfoUzBkld8DCu1BQLDsiKrS3VCQ6uWHSZeoahLsxbvKiG2CKFpx9KP1bPUPe-2TmtFKKMT3DmZtXqTM0vKNJX0GXAjixW4kcVK3KzSEXQadB6sBaqzAqm11a-Cah2sWRc1KI_9Zh5B81zJIvOzwGvfYMhuDdvEHLpJCJPqbONCM4ELmNgcJs3Dt_-g07fySlp9ADe4Z56CrBvT9MEEfRwlNifD_TTY_HL9iJdaIzLEwtDcUcOcoGbD-8_Y8P_TuGfux8qpws4SjTnCdeNgeZJYN0Q8xezw6L7dGQjW9O6-rmwwnSw72RTzpOCRxGLNbBa6ES0sIa5ealG_ejtA61xkgC1DZLKZyJV5t1Kp8PhIxdC728so4SHKYzq3KuZKLXf_MPg1tM7LRY4Xn8g8TwfVNVwlA-yh6ViiW2VquzaU0dlIP3EdU1p7pGAH9mjf6CutL9EpjX3jbpScBKPB4UkLtGT7ShfhKxkMXnf3k2v4-QOuTEVGdmBkmYRtTzsda6e5_q_19w9d6GOMbPPuRlPBIip9q9HZ293ZeRuC-QlC-DLUb4e2o3Qxo5FC00-C04qWdZE1XbSSLsCvqZBTWaRaniBla0VXZfmXaY2gA6o15rrITJrQbVpWWdkI9xCYSEl1w1wmQ2fqVVU46E0xWDu9HJqOlecbCaf8sochJN3xmJOMjseB_VxzX23l19tv)):

```py
# my original
def Kelly(A): 
    min_heap = []
    max_heap = []
    total = 0
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        heappush(min_heap, -heappushpop(max_heap, -a))
        if not i % 3:
            heappush(max_heap, -heappop(min_heap))
        total -= max_heap[0]
    return total

# optimized with local variables push/pop/pushpop
def Kelly2(A):
    push, pop, pushpop = heappush, heappop, heappushpop
    min_heap = []
    max_heap = []
    total = 0
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        push(min_heap, -pushpop(max_heap, -a))
        if not i % 3:
            push(max_heap, -pop(min_heap))
        total -= max_heap[0]
    return total


# trincot's original
def trincot(A):
    min_heap = []
    max_heap = []
    m = []
    for i, value in enumerate(A):  # Use enumerate to get both the index and the value
        if len(max_heap) < i // 3 + 1:
            # If current value would cause a violation of the invariant, exchange it 
            #    with the minimum value in the min heap
            if min_heap and value > min_heap[0]:   
                value = heapq.heappushpop(min_heap, value)
            heapq.heappush(max_heap, -value)
        else:
            # If current value would cause a violation of the invariant, exchange it 
            #    with the maximum value in the max heap
            if value < -max_heap[0]:
                value = -heapq.heappushpop(max_heap, -value)
            heapq.heappush(min_heap, value)
        m.append(-max_heap[0])
    return sum(m)


# optimized to use `total`, `not i % 3`, and no `heapq.`
def trincot2(A):
    min_heap = []
    max_heap = []
    total = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(A):
        if not i % 3:
            if min_heap and value > min_heap[0]:   
                value = heappushpop(min_heap, value)
            heappush(max_heap, -value)
        else:
            if value < -max_heap[0]:
                value = -heappushpop(max_heap, -value)
            heappush(min_heap, value)
        total -= max_heap[0]
    return total


# Let heappushpop do the optimization
def trincot3(A):
    min_heap = []
    max_heap = []
    total = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(A):
        if not i % 3:
            value = heappushpop(min_heap, value)
            heappush(max_heap, -value)
        else:
            value = -heappushpop(max_heap, -value)
            heappush(min_heap, value)
        total -= max_heap[0]
    return total


# optimized with local push/pushpop
def trincot4(A):
    push, pushpop = heappush, heappushpop
    min_heap = []
    max_heap = []
    total = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(A):
        if not i % 3:
            push(max_heap, -pushpop(min_heap, value))
        else:
            push(min_heap, -pushpop(max_heap, -value))
        total -= max_heap[0]
    return total


funcs = Kelly, Kelly2, trincot, trincot2, trincot3, trincot4

from time import time
from statistics import mean, stdev
from heapq import heappush, heappop, heappushpop
import heapq
import random

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    A = random.choices(range(-10**9, 10**9), k=10**5)
    expect = None
    for f in funcs:
        t = time()
        result = f(A)
        times[f].append(time() - t)
        if expect is None:
            expect = result
        else:
            assert result == expect
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
```